# Заполнить столбец числами по порядку

Tags: sql

Как заполнить столбец числами по порядку начиная с 395?

Comment: В автоинкременте, как правило, можно задать начальное значение и шаг.

Comment: СУБД какая используется?

Answer (score 3):

Решение для PostgreSQL:

```
select * from generate_series(365,370) number;

 number 
--------
    365
    366
    367
    368
    369
    370
(6 rows)
```

Вот [здесь](http://blog.jooq.org/2013/11/19/how-to-create-a-range-from-1-to-10-in-sql/) можно найти другие способы.

Answer (score 2):

Решение для MySql

```
create table t (
id int not null INCREMENT,
primary key (id)
)
INCREMENT = 395;
```

---

Для Oracle есть *sequence*

```
create sequence SEQ
start with   395
increment by  1
```

Затем обращение к последовательности

```
insert into YOUR_TABLE (ATTR_1, ATTR_2)
values (SEQ.NEXTVAL, "smth");
```